# Workaround to run Sonobuoy e2e tests on K8S cluster having node taints

Tags: kubernetes, e2e-testing

I'm trying to run E2E Kubernetes tests using Sonobuoy, but if one of the nodes has custom taints (NoSchedule) I'm getting

```
Nov 26 08:31:14.626: INFO: >>> kubeConfig: /tmp/kubeconfig-744133672
Nov 26 08:31:14.635: INFO: Waiting up to 30m0s for all (but 0) nodes to be schedulable
Nov 26 09:01:14.652: INFO: Unexpected error occurred: timed out waiting for the condition
Failure [1800.028 seconds]
BeforeSuite] BeforeSuite 
/workspace/anago-v1.12.1-beta.0.52+4ed3216f3ec431/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/test/e2e/e2e.go:137

Expected error:
<*errors.errorString | 0xc4200836b0>: {
s: "timed out waiting for the condition",
}
timed out waiting for the condition
not to have occurred

/workspace/anago-v1.12.1-beta.0.52+4ed3216f3ec431/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/test/e2e/e2e.go:175
```

Kubernetes version is 1.12. If I remove taints in my test cluster E2E tests passed successfully.

I've found that it was fixed in 1.17 version (see: https://github.com/vmware-tanzu/sonobuoy/issues/599 https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/74282 https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.17.md )

Is there a workaround to run e2e tests on production 1.12 Kubernetes cluster having node taints? Except for waiting for 1.17 version and cluster upgrade of course.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a workaround for kubernetes versions prior to 1.17.

---

On **kubernetes version v1.16** you can run Sonobuoy (Sonobuoy version v0.16.1 or higher) with providing the test framework flag: `--allowed-not-ready-nodes=1`

- then the test framework allows 1 node (your tainted node) to be "not-ready"
- this approach works fine for me with kubernetes v1.16.4 and Sonobuoy Version: v0.17.1
- see docs here: [We have some nodes with custom taints in our cluster and the tests won't start. How can I run the tests?](https://github.com/vmware-tanzu/sonobuoy/blob/master/site/docs/master/faq.md#we-have-some-nodes-with-custom-taints-in-our-cluster-and-the-tests-wont-start-how-can-i-run-the-tests)
- the Sonobuoy invocation looks like:

```
sonobuoy run --plugin-env=e2e.E2E_EXTRA_ARGS="--allowed-not-ready-nodes=1"
```

---

And on **kubernetes version prior to v1.16** it was more complicated. I haven't tested this but according to docs:

- you should also use the test framework flag: `--allowed-not-ready-nodes=1`
- Before kubernetes v1.16, it was necessary to build your own custom image which could execute the tests with the desired options. See docs at:

  - [How can I run the E2E tests with certain test framework options set? What are the available options?](https://github.com/vmware-tanzu/sonobuoy/blob/master/site/docs/master/faq.md#how-can-i-run-the-e2e-tests-with-certain-test-framework-options-set-what-are-the-available-options)
  - [Building Your Own Test Image](https://sonobuoy.io/custom-e2e-image/#building-your-own-test-image)